# How to map multiple columns of one table to single parent column of another table using Spring JPA using Hibernate`

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to map 3 columns of address (country, state,city) to the configuration table id column.

I have the following table structure:

**Address Model/table**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private Configuration configuration;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private int country;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private int state;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private int city;

    private int zipCode;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    private String status;
    private String deleteFlag;
}
```

**Configuration Model/Table**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "configurations")
public class Configuration {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private long id;

     @NotNull
     private String configurationName;

     @NotNull
     private String configurationType;

     @NotNull
     private String ConfigurationDescription;

     @Column(name = "parent_id")
     private long parentId;
}
```

Here, i am unable to map the relationship between Configuration and Address and Configuration with itself.

Please friends help me in this regards.

**Updated**

```
**Configurations Table record**

id configname  configtype  configdescription parentid created_at  updated_at Status deleteflag
1  India       Country     This is a country  0       12-05-2016  Null Active Null
2  Delhi       State       This is a State    1       12-05-2016  Null Active Null
3  New Delhi   City        This is a city     2       12-05-2016  Null Active Null
----------

**Address Table record**

id Country State City zipcode created_at updated_at status deleteflag
1      1     2     3  110034  12-05-2016  Null       Active  Null
```

Comment: do you want an association between Address and Configuration ????

Comment: I have updated what i want, please look.

Comment: you want to map the state city and country member in your address class to the corresponding row in Configuration .. am I rt??

Comment: Yes. that's i want. I am also looking for the alternative like joined sub class, or table per class etc.

Comment: please see the update  below in  my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to map the three field from address to Configuration. There are basically two things that you want .

When you try to save a new configuration you want the id of the configuration to be set automatically by using the associated address of the configuration. For this you would have to create a Custom identifier generations strategy .
To  write your Custom Identifier generator see this http://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/custom-generator-class-in-hibernate.html

When you would want to set the id yourself without using automatic identifier generation . For this just remove the @GeneratedValue annotation from your id member in Configuration class.Now you would have to set the identifier yourself using the three property from Address. You can create an association between Configuration and Address.

I don't see any other reason why you would want map the three property  of one entity to id property of other entity.

**UPDATE**

Change your Address entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country")
    private Configuration country;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state")
    private Configuration state;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
    private Configuration city;

    @Column(name="zipcode") 
    private int zipCode;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
     @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "deleteFlag")
    private String deleteFlag;
```

}

IN the above configuration you map the Configuration entity in one to one relationship with address once for state , city and country.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Tables created automatically. Let me see it also working for front end.