# hibernate - mutiple many-to-one to the same entity column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a relationship between buildings and floors: some floors can only be in 1 building (these floors will have only 1 foreign key to "building" table) and there are some floors sit between 2 buildings (these floors will have 2 foreign keys to "building" table, one is `startBuildingId` and the second is `endBuildingId`).I have this code to represent this relationship:

```
public class Building implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building")
    private Set<Floor> floors = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Floor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("floors")
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
    private Building building;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    @JoinColumn(name = "start_building_id")
    private Building startBuildingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    @JoinColumn(name = "end_building_id")
    private Building endBuildingId;
}
```

When I create a floor that is sits between 2 buildings, I've chosen the `startBuildingId` and `endBuildingId`, but when I retrieve all the floors from the building's `private Set<Floor> floors`, it only shows the other floors, not those floors that sit between 2 buildings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer help ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180350/how-to-map-multiple-columns-of-one-table-to-single-parent-column-of-another-tabl/38181546

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

- Three @OneToMany fields
- a method that returns a union of them

I assume you don't do any modifications on the floors list (adding a Floor would not be clearly defined - does it belong to a single building, or is it shared). In this case, it can be a lazy, unmodifiable view on the actual sets.

Alternatively (and preferably), you can easily create a JPQL/Criteria query that finds all the floors by building id.

Comment: so the use of bidirectional one-to-many here is correct? Because i was wrong with my code, i thought i should use many-to-many

Comment: Use what you need to use, OneToMany Vs ManyToMany  is a domain modeling decision, not a technical detail. Both approaches I proposed work for many to many as well .

Comment: Thank you, i thought that OneToMany and ManyToMany map to relationship in the database, could you suggest any keywords on this topic.

Comment: Both map to a relationship in the database, but it is usually implemented differently. For many to many you need a join table. For one to many join table with a unique constraint for the collection elements, but more efficient mapping uses only a foreign key in collection elements. Besides arity, there are other considerations. For one to many, the lifetime of collection elements is bound to the parent, so for example deletes can be cascaded. This is not the case for many to many.